# paypal sandbox form not working, The connection has timed out error

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am using beiow form to make payment using PayPal.

```
<?php
$url = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
$price=90.00;
//$url = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
?>
<form action="<?=$url?>" method="post" style="padding: 0; margin: 0;">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" />
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="xyz@gmail.com" />
    <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="full licence" />
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?=$price?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="shipping" value="0" />
    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://www.example.com/ipn.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.example.com/dev/login/success.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://www.example.com/dev/login/paypal_cancel.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP" />
    <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2" >
    <input type="image" border="0" name="paypal" src="images/btn_paypal_nl.gif" onClick=""/>
</form>
```

All thing is working if i change `$url` to live account. But if i use sandbox URL, then browser takes too much time and at the end return `The connection has timed out` error.

Comment: Are you behind a firewall? you may need to open that IP. Also the PayPal sandbox is far from reliable try again in a while and may be back.

Comment: @Juan no firewall. i am trying let us see. is there any other possiblity?

Comment: Its seems to be working fine for me right now. Can you telnet that ip?